# Невидимая граница на холсте в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Работаю над примитивным арканоидом на питоне в tkinter, создаю холст 1000x600, упаковываю, и потом начинаю на нем создавать обьекты. Возникла проблема - когда я пытаюсь слишком низко на холсте рисовать, обьекты почему то смещаются вверх, хотя место ниже есть. Если же я принудительно рисую фигуры ниже, то их становится видно только частично.

x, y, size_x и size_y в данном случае равны 1.

```
def create_object(self, canvas: Canvas):
    if self.instance is None:
        height = int(canvas['height'])
        coordinates = [self.x * 8,
                       height - self.y * 8,
                       (self.x + self.size_x) * 8,
                       height - (self.y + self.size_y) * 8]
        self.instance = canvas.create_rectangle(coordinates[0],
                                                coordinates[1],
                                                coordinates[2],
                                                coordinates[3],
                                                fill='white')
        print(f'Initial coordinates: {coordinates}\nCanvas coordinates: {canvas.coords(self.instance)}')
```

Вот что рисуется в изначальном случае:[image]

Логи:
Initial coordinates: [16, 584, 24, 576]
Canvas coordinates: [16.0, 576.0, 24.0, 584.0]

Если же я пытаюсь принудительно ввести другие координаты:

```
self.instance = canvas.create_rectangle(coordinates[0],
                                            579,
                                            coordinates[2],
                                            coordinates[3],
                                            fill='white')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Логи: Initial coordinates: [16, 584, 24, 576]
Canvas coordinates: [16.0, 576.0, 24.0, 579.0]

Как можно было бы убрать эту границу на холсте?

Comment: Не очень понятно про какую границу идет речь. Попробовал подобный код переписать с прямым указанием координат, никаких границ не вижу все отображается как я ожидаю: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdg26.png Возможно ошибка в коде вычисления координат.

Comment: Вот то же самое с "непрямым" указанием координат, тут видна серая граница самого canvas слева, но ее можно отключить: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkmPB.png В остальном никаких проблем не вижу.

Comment: @insolor да, благодарю, в итоге убрал границу самого canvas, это помогло.